# How can i get android native java debuging codes with codenameone

Tags: java, android, apk, codenameone

is there a way or feature that give us possibility to see the native android codes after debugging the project with codenameone? right now we are just seeing the .apk file from the project not android java source.
I want to explore the android java source and editing them.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger in eclipse or Android studio?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Upon next build, your changes would get overwritten. I think development in Codename One is even more comfortable than native android since the emulator starts a lot quicker and debugging from within netbeans is really neat. With one or two minor glitches, everything worked on my real device as it did in the emulator.

Comment: thanks but i want to use codenameone as convertor, convert my java codes to android java, objective-c, c# and more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only useful for debugging, converting then using the sources is pointless as mentioned in the comments since the C code generated for iOS is not maintainable (its over 2000 files for a simple app).

To do this just use the include source feature: http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-the-include-sources-feature-to-debug-the-native-code-on-iosandroid-etc.html